# How to create links based on multiple checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html

My html code is like this

```
<form>
<p>Please select the topics you want to learn about.</p>
        Overfishing & Destructive fishing <input type="checkbox" name="learn" value="fishing" id="fishing" /><br/>
        How climate change affects the ocean <input type="checkbox" name="learn" value="climate" id="climate"/><br/>
        Plastic pollution <input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="plastic" id="plastic"/><br/>
        Marine Life fun facts <input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="funfacts" id="funfacts"/><br/>
</form>
<button type="submit" onclick="addinfofunction()">Submit</button>
```

I'm trying to display links based on the selected checkboxes

Javascript is like this so far

```
var a = "color: red;"
var x = "https://teamseas.org/"
var b ="blank"
var y = "https://act.oceana.org/page/95375/donate/1?ea.tracking.id=Redirect"
var z = "https://reefresilience.org/stressors/local-stressors/overfishing-and-destructive-fishing-threats/"
var c = "https://www.conservation.org/blog/5-ways-that-climate-change-affects-the-ocean"
var d = "https://www.biologicaldiversity.org/campaigns/ocean_plastics/"
var e = "https://oceana.org/marine-life/"
function addinfofunction() {
  if(document.getElementById('q_yes').checked){
    document.getElementById('donate').innerHTML = "<h3 style='"+a+"''>Donation List<h3><a href='"+x+"' target='"+b+"'><h4>For Every dollar donated a pound of trash gets removed from the sea</a><h4><p>-Team Seas</p><a href='"+y+"' target='"+b+"'><h4>Provides policy recommendation on a global scale to help Ocean conservacy</h4></a><p>-Oceana</p>"
  }
  if (document.getElementById('fishing').checked){
    document.getElementById('learn').innerHTML = "<h3 style='"+a+"''>Topic Links<h3><a href='"+z+"' target='"+b+"'><h4>Overfishing & Destructive fishing</a>"
      if (document.getElementById('fishing').checked){
        if (document.getElementById('climate').checked){
          document.getElementById('learn').innerHTML = "<h3 style='"+a+"''>Topic Links<h3><a href='"+z+"' target='"+b+"'><h4>Overfishing & Destructive fishing</a><a href='"+c+"' target='"+b+"'><h4>How climate change affects the ocean</a>"}}}    
      if (document.getElementById('fishing').checked){
        if (document.getElementById('climate').checked){
          if (document.getElementById('plastic').checked){
            document.getElementById('learn').innerHTML = "<h3 style='"+a+"''>Topic Links<h3><a href='"+z+"' target='"+b+"'><h4>Overfishing & Destructive fishing</a><a href='"+c+"' target='"+b+"'><h4>How climate change affects the ocean</a><a href='"+d+"' target='"+b+"'><h4>Plastic Pollution</a>"}}}
      if (document.getElementById('fishing').checked){
        if (document.getElementById('climate').checked){
          if (document.getElementById('plastic').checked){
            if (document.getElementById('funfacts').checked){
            document.getElementById('learn').innerHTML = "<h3 style='"+a+"''>Topic Links<h3><a href='"+z+"' target='"+b+"'><h4>Overfishing & Destructive fishing</a><a href='"+c+"' target='"+b+"'><h4>How climate change affects the ocean</a><a href='"+d+"' target='"+b+"'><h4>Plastic Pollution</a><a href='"+e+"' target='"+b+"'><h4>Marine Life fun facts</a>"}}}}
```

Is there a quicker way than hard coding this.

Comment: For code that is *working* that you desire a review of, you may find it more on-topic on [Code Review.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `FormData` to collect the values from the form. (It creates a set of key/value pairs representing form fields and their values).

Create an object to store the urls as opposed to some randomly named variables.

Access the object based on the formdata keys to get the relevant url.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form')

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  form.querySelectorAll('.myLink').forEach((link) => {
    link.remove()
  })
  const formData = new FormData(form)
  for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
    const cb = form.querySelector(`#${pair[1]}`)
    var tempA = document.createElement('a');
    tempA.href = links[pair[1]]
    tempA.innerHTML = pair[1]
    tempA.classList.add('myLink')
    cb.insertAdjacentElement('afterEnd', tempA)
  }
})


const links = {
  fishing: 'www.fishing.com',
  climate: 'www.climate.com',
  plastic: 'www.plastic.com',
  funfacts: 'www.funfacts.com'
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p>Please select the topics you want to learn about.</p>
  Overfishing & Destructive fishing <input type="checkbox" name="learn" value="fishing" id="fishing" /><br/> How climate change affects the ocean <input type="checkbox" name="learn" value="climate" id="climate" /><br/> Plastic pollution <input type="checkbox"
    name="sports" value="plastic" id="plastic" /><br/> Marine Life fun facts <input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="funfacts" id="funfacts" /><br/>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

For ease of maintainability and reduction of repetitive scripting, you could hard code those information buckets, keep them hidden and reveal them dynamically....

```js
function addinfofunction() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.result')
     .forEach(div => div.setAttribute('hidden', ''));
  document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked')
     .forEach(el => document.querySelector(`#res-${el.getAttribute('id')}`)?.removeAttribute('hidden'));
}
```

```css
.result {
  margin: 10px 0;
  border-top: 1px dashed #ccc;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false">
  <p>Please select the topics you want to learn about.</p>
  Overfishing & Destructive fishing <input type="checkbox" name="learn" value="fishing" id="fishing" /><br/> How climate change affects the ocean <input type="checkbox" name="learn" value="climate" id="climate" /><br/> Plastic pollution <input type="checkbox"
    name="sports" value="plastic" id="plastic" /><br/> Marine Life fun facts <input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="funfacts" id="funfacts" /><br/>
</form>
<button type="submit" onclick="addinfofunction()">Submit</button>

<div class='result' id='res-fishing' hidden>
  <h4>Fishing</h4>
  <p>Blah blah blah</p>
  <a href='#'>A link with more about that</a>
</div>

<div class='result' id='res-climate' hidden>
  <h4>Climate</h4>
  <p>Blah blah blah</p>
  <a href='#'>A link with more about that</a>
</div>

<div class='result' id='res-plastic' hidden>
  <h4>Plastic</h4>
  <p>Blah blah blah</p>
  <a href='#'>A link with more about that</a>
</div>

<div class='result' id='res-funfacts' hidden>
  <h4>Fun Facts</h4>
  <p>Blah blah blah</p>
  <a href='#'>A link with more about that</a>
</div>
```